# IF, ELSE statement in php UPDATE script?

Tags: php

I have a php UPDATE script that is updating a row in a database with information typed into a form.

I have a column named: `status`

and a column named: `resolved`

I need to change `resolved` to `1` if `status` is equal to `Done` otherwise `resolved` needs to be `0`.

I came up with this but it does not seem to be working, the code runs just fine with no errors. But the resolved field doesn't change.

```
 ...

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE affiliate_tasks SET status= '$_POST[task_status_edit]',task_name = '$_POST[task_name_edit]',due_date = '$_POST[task_date_edit]',if ($_POST[task_status_edit] == 'Done') {
    resolved = '1'
}
else{
    resolved = '0'
    }
WHERE task_id='$_POST[task_id]'");


echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/affiliates/task.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('A task was updated!')) . '">';

?>
```

Comment: Print out the mysqli error message. That's not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in /home/content/38/10473938/html/website/panda/affiliates/scripts/form_scripts/user_tasks_update.php on line 17
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (Overdue == 'Done') { resolved = '1' } else{ resolved = '0' } WHERE task_i' at line 1

Comment: Using `mysqli` does not prevent sql injection itself. You need to validate user input. The cleanest way is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so...

```
if($_POST['task_status_edit']=='Done'){
  $resolved =1;} else {$resolved=0;}


mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE affiliate_tasks SET resolved='$resolved', status= '$_POST[task_status_edit]',task_name = '$_POST[task_name_edit]',due_date = '$_POST[task_date_edit]' WHERE task_id='$_POST[task_id]'");
```

Or the easier, one liner way...

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE affiliate_tasks SET status= '$_POST[task_status_edit]', task_name = '$_POST[task_name_edit]', due_date = '$_POST[task_date_edit]', resolved=".($_POST[task_status_edit] == 'Done')?1:0 ." WHERE task_id='$_POST[task_id]'");
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/content/38/10473938/html/website/panda/affiliates/scripts/form_scripts/user_tasks_update.php on line 9

Answer (score 4):

you are mixing PHP in your SQL statement, thus creating an invalid statement (and this is exactly what the error message tells you: `You have an error in your SQL syntax`). Rememeber: SQL is PHP agnostic.

You should check the value of `$_POST[task_status_edit]` **before** you run the query, and set the `resolved` variable accordingly.
Then run the query:

```
$resolved = $_POST['task_status_edit'])=='Done'?1:0;

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE affiliate_tasks 
                   SET resolved='$resolved', 
                       status= '$_POST[task_status_edit]',
                       task_name = '$_POST[task_name_edit]',
                       due_date = '$_POST[task_date_edit]' 
                   WHERE task_id='$_POST[task_id]'");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
($_POST[task_status_edit] == 'Done')?1:0;
```

You can add replace this with the if else structure:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE affiliate_tasks SET status= '$_POST[task_status_edit]',
task_name = '$_POST[task_name_edit]',
due_date = '$_POST[task_date_edit]',
resolved=".($_POST[task_status_edit] == 'Done')?1:0 ."
WHERE task_id='$_POST[task_id]'");
```